Optimizing Code for Scrapping Room Tables
I want to extract the room tables for all hotels on the website.
I will also provide a sample link.
I have prepared the following code as well,
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
# -------------------------------------------Click meeting room grid button
try:
    meeting_room_grid_button = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="meetingSpaceView"]/li[2]/label')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", meeting_room_grid_button)
    time.sleep(10)
except NoSuchElementException:
    pass
# -------------------------------------------Scroll and Show All Btn
try:
    scroll_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    show_all_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".MeetingRoomsGrid__viewAllToggleContainer___2HJRU button")))
    ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(show_all_button).click().perform()
    time.sleep(13)
except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException, TimeoutException):
    pass
# -------------------------------------------Slider
try:
    horizontal_bar_width = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                               'div.ScrollbarLayout_face.ScrollbarLayout_faceHorizontal.public_Scrollbar_face').rect[
        'width']
    slider = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                 'div.ScrollbarLayout_face.ScrollbarLayout_faceHorizontal.public_Scrollbar_face')
except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException):
    slider = []
# -------------------------------------------Extract Table_Part1
cell_list1 = []
columns_list1 = []
df_part1 = pd.DataFrame()
for element in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroup'):
    if element.text.split('\n') != ['']:
        cell_list1.append(element.text.split('\n'))
if len(cell_list1) != 0:
    columns_list1 = ['Meeting rooms'] + cell_list1[1]
    df_part1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns_list1)
    i = 2
    while i < len(cell_list1):
        for item in cell_list1[i]:
            if item.startswith('View details'):
                cell_list1[i].remove(item)
        row = "'" + ("','".join(cell_list1[i])) + "'"
        df_part1.loc[row] = cell_list1[i] + cell_list1[i + 1]
        i = i + 2
    df_part1.insert(0, "title", title)
# -------------------------------------------Move Slider
try:
    if slider != []:
        ActionChains(driver).click_and_hold(slider).move_by_offset(600, 0).release().perform()
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 0)")
    while True:
        try:
            Next_button = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                              'span.Icons-All__right___2HnMG.Icons-All__icon___3TnCZ.MeetingRoomsGrid__navIcon___cXWdw[aria-label="Next"]')
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(Next_button).click().perform()
            time.sleep(60)
        except:
            break
except (NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException):
    pass
# -------------------------------------------Extract Table_Part2
cell_list2 = []
columns_list2 = []
df_part2 = pd.DataFrame()
for element in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.fixedDataTableCellGroupLayout_cellGroup'):
    if element.text.split('\n') != ['']:
        cell_list2.append(element.text.split('\n'))
if len(cell_list2) != 0:
    print(cell_list2)
    if len(cell_list2[0]) != 1:
        if len(cell_list2[0]) ==2:
            del cell_list2[0]
            cell_list2.insert(0, ['Meeting rooms'])
        else:
            cell_list2.insert(0, ['Meeting rooms'])
    if ['Meeting rooms'] in cell_list2[1]:
        del cell_list2[1]
    if len(cell_list2[1]) != len(cell_list2[3]):
        del cell_list2[1][0:(len(cell_list2[1]) - len(cell_list2[3]))]
    columns_list2 = ['Meeting rooms'] + cell_list2[1]
    df_part2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns_list2)
    j = 2
    print(cell_list2)
    while j < len(cell_list2):
        for item in cell_list2[j]:
            if item.startswith('View details'):
                cell_list2[j].remove(item)
        row = "'" + ("','".join(cell_list2[j])) + "'"
        df_part2.loc[row] = cell_list2[j] + cell_list2[j + 1]
        j = j + 2
    df_part2.insert(0, "title", title)
# -------------------------------------------Extract Table_Part 3
script = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//script[contains(.,'{&quot;id&quot;')]")))
pattern = r'{"id":"([^"]+)"'
script_text = html.unescape(script.get_property('innerText'))
links = re.findall(pattern, script_text.split('"badges"')[0])
roomlinks = []
for l in links:
    substring = url[:url.find("?")]
    roomlinks.append(f"{substring}/meetingRoom-{l}")

room_list = []
for link in roomlinks[1:]:
    print(link)
    driver.get(link)
    time.sleep(10)
    roomtitle = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.MeetingRoomDetailPage__meetingRoomNameText___3k-3T').text
    roomAbout = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                    'div.Grid__col___gBFRS.MeetingRoomDetailPage__descriptionContainer___36ypu.Grid__col-xs-12___2eswl.Grid__col-xs-offset-0___aTK-4.Grid__col-sm-6___CaUu-.Grid__col-sm-offset-0___tTaDk.Grid__col-md-offset-0___2SImQ.Grid__col-lg-offset-0___Atw2J').text
    try:
        roomImg = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                      "//IMG[@data-cvent-id='roomProfile-row0-col1-styleImageContainer-imageContainer-canvas-picture-img']").get_attribute(
            'src')
    except:
        roomImg = ""

    try:
        roomFloorPlan = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                            "a.MeetingRoomDetailPage__downloadFloorPlans___1E1OW").get_attribute(
            'href')
    except:
        roomFloorPlan = ""

    try:
        roomFloorPlanImg = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                               "//IMG[@data-cvent-id='roomProfile-row0-col1-styleImageContainer-imageContainer-canvas-img']").get_attribute(
            'src')
    except:
        roomFloorPlanImg = ""

    roomAmenitiesVar = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                            'h5.MeetingRoomDetailPage__amenityListTitle___1jM5Q')
    roomAmenitiesAm = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                                           'div.Grid__col___gBFRS.MeetingRoomDetailPage__amenityList___3XlFG.Grid__col-xs-12___2eswl.Grid__col-xs-offset-0___aTK-4.Grid__col-sm-6___CaUu-.Grid__col-sm-offset-0___tTaDk.Grid__col-md-offset-0___2SImQ.Grid__col-lg-offset-0___Atw2J ul')
    roomAmenities = {}
    for v, a in zip(roomAmenitiesVar, roomAmenitiesAm):
        roomAmenities[v.text] = a.text

    row_values = [roomtitle, roomAbout, roomImg, roomFloorPlan, roomFloorPlanImg]
    room_list.append(row_values)

df_part3 = pd.DataFrame(room_list, columns=['Meeting rooms', 'Description', 'Image', 'Floor Plan',
                                            'Floor Plan Image'])
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
finalldf = pd.merge(df_part1, df_part3, on='Meeting rooms', how='outer')
# -------------------------------------------Extract Common Col list
common_col = ["title"] + list(set(finalldf.columns).intersection(columns_list2))

if df_part1.empty:
    pass
else:
    finalDF = pd.merge(finalldf, df_part2, on=common_col, how='outer')

but I have two problems:

It may require more scrolling for some hotels to scrape the data. In the code I wrote, it scrolls only once and retrieves the data.
For some hotels, when scrolling to the right, it retains repetitive columns from the previous scroll but does not display the data correctly. This means that a value might correspond to one column, but when scrolling to the right, the table gets disorganized and displays the same value for a different column. I'll add the image below.
(https://i.sstatic.net/65vL0quB.png)

And the code I wrote is very heavy and inefficient because I am new to this field. Is it possible to guide me on how I can optimize this code to solve these problems? Or is there a more suitable method for extracting these types of tables?

The word for peeling information off a web site is "scrape". To "scrap" something is to discard it as useless, or recycle it (scrap metal).

Indeed, Selenium might be not the best choice for this project.
Before you decide which tools to use for scrapping, it's very important to figure out how a webpage loads the necessary data and where it's stored.
In your case, it's all stored in a javascript variable as a part of the html/script under the name venueProfile. Which means, by simply opening the webpage, you already have the complete dataset. So the only remaining step is parsing the data to make it usable.
Here is how it can be done. And obviously, this can be expanded further depending on your needs.
import json
import requests
import re
import html

# Getting the webpage content
url = 'https://www.cvent.com/venues/en-US/dubai/hotel/jw-marriott-marquis-hotel-dubai/venue-c6d701db-da99-4133-a3de-608d446d3446'
req = requests.get(url)

# Parsing the data which is stored in "venueProfile" variable of javascript
venue_profile_string = re.search('(?<="venueProfile":").+?(?=",)', req.text).group(0)

# Dealing with escape characters
data_string = html.unescape(venue_profile_string).replace('\\\"', '"')

# Converting to python dict
data = json.loads(data_string)

Finally, you can unpack the data as you wish. Below are a few examples of the output.
>>> len(data['meetingRooms'])
47

>>> data['meetingRooms'][9]['name']
'Dubai Ballroom'

>>> data['meetingRooms'][9]['totalSpace']
{'imperialValue': 14983.369751245924, 'metricValue': 1392.0}

>>> data['meetingRooms'][9]['maxCapacity']
1380

